# Nuance- tagging out value of alpha numeric entry

Tags: xml

I am very new to Nuance and grammar files, we have created a grammar that accepts an alpha numeric entry from our caller and then uses a constraint file to improve the accuracy of the speech recognition.

The entry portion of the grammar is working great, but we are unable to tag out the results, below is a snippet from the section of the grammar in question.

ruleref uri="builtin:grammar/alphanum?language=en-US;entries=file://Testfile.TXT"

tag>out._value += rules.latest()

After the reco is complete we are getting [object swijs_global_class] back in the output XML as the tagged value entered by the caller.   We would anticipate seeing something like A B C 1 2 3 as the output.   (an alphanumeric entry 3-10 digits in length)

Any suggestions on how to tag this properly so the value the caller entered is returned in the XML output?

Answer (score 0):

To properly access the Nuance builtin grammar returns with tag-format="semantics/1.0", you need to pull the result from the MEANING object passed back from the engine.  For example:

```
     <ruleref uri="builtin:grammar/creditcard?language=en-US"/>
     <tag>
        if (rules.latest().MEANING){ out = rules.latest().MEANING }
     </tag>
```